# Braintree paypal implementation to django-python

Tags: python, django, paypal, braintree

I'm new with this and making site(I have stripe but ı want paypal too). Can someone explain to me what should I do here. I installed braintree but and added to its js to basehtml then I'm stuck.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/start/hello-server

for instance,

```
import braintree

braintree.Configuration.configure(braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                              merchant_id="use_your_merchant_id",
```

where should I put it. view.py or somewhere another place?

Answer (score 2):

They have a perfectly good API that tells you exactly what to do. Also, check out [django-braintree](https://github.com/Tivix/django-braintree).

Add the `braintree.Configuration.configure(braintree.Environment.Sandbox, merchant_id="use_your_merchant_id",` in settings.py. Generate a client token and send that to your frontend and put that into the `dropin.js` - and you're done.

Comment: thanks for answering. I did it but this @app.route("/purchases", methods=["POST"])
def create_purchase():
  nonce = request.form["payment_method_nonce"]
  # Use payment method nonce here... for view.py, I think. But, İt is giving  a error.

Comment: What kind of error? You need to put more information in order for people to help you.

Comment: sorry. it is saying name 'app' is not defined

Comment: @newbee I work at Braintree. Our Python examples are for using the Flask framework, not Django. You'll need to adapt them to how Django works.

Comment: @agf Maybe Braintree has plans of putting up an example for Django? 